# Java library that generates diff of two Json file

Tags: java, json, diff

Is there any Java library that shows diff of two Json files. I am aware of [Zjsonpatch](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch) , [DiffSon](https://github.com/gnieh/diffson) and [json-patch](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch/blob/master/README.md) java library, but is there any other library that performs the diff and which is the recommended one.

Answer (score 1):

If you can parse the JSON to a `Map`, you can use Guava's [`Maps.difference()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-) to generate a diff.

Comment: I am looking for some java library that can give output in pretty print format in Console, something like http://www.jsondiff.com/

Comment: That's a great solution. Thanks!!
But how to handle cases where I have nested json like {x:y, a:{b:1, c:2}} Here, how to compare value of a, i.e. a:{b:1, c:2}

Comment: @shmosel Parsing this JSON to a Map `["a", "b"]` fails.